# two components rendering at the same level despite z-index

Tags: css-position, z-index

So I've got two components inside my home component and I want one of them (context menu) to render in front of the other (side bar) but they're rendering at the same level, so you can see the side bar through the context menu. What am I doing wrong, or what do I need to change?

```
<home>
  <div *ngIf="contextmenu" class="contextmenudiv">
    <context-menu [x]="x" [y]="y"></context-menu>
  </div>

  <side-bar></side-bar>
</home>
```

side-bar css:

```
z-index: 0;
width: 25%;
position: absolute;
right: 1%;
```

contextmenudiv:

```
z-index: 11;
display: block;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

context-menu:

```
z-index: 11;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

I've tried adding `position: absolute` to my context-menu and they still render at the same level. What do I need to do to get the context-menu to render in front of the sidebar?

Answer (score 0):

Immediately after I posted this question, I found a solution.
I literally just needed to add a relatively high z-index to the outermost div inside the context-menu component.